# Yet an other i = i++

Tags: c

I have encountered a sorcery today.

http://codepad.org/VW2vTpWw

Language: `C`

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i = 5;
    i = i++;
    printf ("%i", i);
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

How? Why?

This is supposed to be tricky code but the other way around. The negligent programmer would think that `i = i++` is just simple increment but it's not. Yet it works like one here. It's supposed to be `5`! Like in [JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/MeFte/).

What should be happening.

1. `i` gets the value of `5`.
2. `i++` returns `5`.
3. `i` is post incremented by `i++` (to `6`).
4. `i` gets the value of `5` (returned by `i++`).
5. the value of `i` (`5`) gets printed.

Yet it is `6`.

I haven't been able to find a description to this on SO, or the whole internet (just the [other way around](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/75195/ii#)).

What is broken here?

Please explain.

Comment: This is an undefined behaviour. See here for reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: "It's supposed to be...". No, it's undefined.

Comment: Ok I'm flagging my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: @SukritKalra Thanks for the link, the answers there are quite descriptive, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to store more than once to an object without an intervening sequence point.

In particular, your step 3 and 4 have no defined ordering, the increment (and store) or the store could happen first.

Comment: I'll accept this after reading the wikipedia article about sequence points.